# Update query in SQL Server isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a class method for updating database.. but it isn't working and I can't find out what is wrong..

There is no error in the `try catch` block.. in database type of `id` is `int` and type of `catagory` is `nvarchar(50)`.

I also tried converting `id` from `int` to `string` but doesn't work and no error..

Database column name and variable name is same. Connection string is saved in `web.config` file which worked for inserting data.

```
public string update(int id, string catagory)
{
        //creating database connection
        SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        objConnection.Open();
        string error = "";

        try
        {
            //firing command
            string strCommand = "UPDATE Data SET catagory = '" + catagory + "' WHERE (id = '" + id + "')";
            SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(strCommand, objConnection);
            objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            error = ex.ToString();
        }

        //closing database connection
        objConnection.Close();

        return error;
    }
```

Comment: Do not concatenate strings into SQL commands, this makes your code prone to SQL injection attacks and it is less efficient. Use parameterized queries instead. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182310.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also, it's a **category** (not a *catagory*)

Answer (score 3):

If `id` column is `int`, you don't need to use single quotes with it. Just use it like `WHERE (id = " + id + ")`. Single quotes is for character column types.

### But don't use this way

You should always use *[parameterized queries](http://codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)*. This kind of string concatenations are open for *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks.

```
string strCommand = "UPDATE Data SET catagory = @catagory WHERE id = @id";
SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(strCommand, objConnection);
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catagory", catagory);
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also `DATA` could be *[reserved keyword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)* in future releases of SQL Server. You might need to use it in square brackets like `[DATA]` in the future.

Use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` by the way.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** `DATA`  could be Reserved word in future versions of SqlServer.

From MSDN :

> Data could be reserved in future releases of SQL Server as new
>   features are implemented.

**Solution :** enclose the Reserved words in square brackets as `[data]`
Try This:

```
string strCommand = "UPDATE [Data] SET catagory = '" + catagory + "' WHERE (id = " + id + ")";
```

**Suggestion 1:** you don't need to enclose the Integer parameters within single quotes.

**Suggestion 2 :** your Update query is open to sqlinjection attacks please use Parameterised queries to avoid them.

**Suggestion 3:** you could use the `return` value of the `ExecuteNonQuery()` method to identify the Status of the `UPDATE` command.

**Complete Code:** using `Parameterised Queries`

```
    try
    {
        //firing command

        string strCommand = "UPDATE [Data] SET catagory = @catagory WHERE (id =@id)";
        SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(strCommand, objConnection);
        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catagory",catagory);
        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",id);
        int status;
        status = objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if(status>0)
           MessageBox.Show("Data Updated Successfully!");
        else
           MessageBox.Show("Update Failed!");

    }
```

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi `DATA` is not a reserved keyword right now. But it can be in the future. This is not the _main_ reason why OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: @SonerGönül: yes dear i just now found that information :) Thanks for your remainder.

Comment: @SonerGönül i tried like you but still after refreshing database it isnt changed..

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi You get any exception or error message? Are you sure your connection string is right? Give us more details.

Comment: @WahidMasud: so did you try with my latest code using `status`? try with altest code and see what wether it returns success or failure message?

Comment: @Sudhakar Tillapudi i tried like you and it say SUCCESS..but when i come back to VS10 and refresh database i see it isnt changed..:s

Comment: @WahidMasud: there is no problem with the code, only thing you need to check is wether you are refering to proper database on not.please check with your connection string database and the one which you are verifying both are same

Comment: i rechecked connection string..still no result..looks like im having a really bad day..:(

Comment: @WahidMasud: restrt the IDE and connect back to database and see if the chages are there or not.

Comment: i restarted my pc and guess what still nothing changes..:)

Answer (score 0):

Always use parameterized queries, for anti [injection](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommand).

1. The first parameter specifies the SQL statement.
2. The second parameter is the SqlConnection.
3. The third parameter is the SqlTransaction.
   here is a [reference](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommand)

And `using statement` automatically dispose and close your `sql connection` and `sql command`

```
     public string update(int id, string catagory)
            {
                    //creating database connection
                   using( SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
            {
                    objConnection.Open();
                    string error = "";

                    try
                    {
                        string strCommand = "UPDATE Data SET catagory = @catagory WHERE id = @id ";
                        using( SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(strCommand, objConnection))
                       {
                        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catagory",catagory);
                        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",id);
                        objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                       }
                    }
                    catch(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
                    {
                        error = ex.ToString();
                    }

                    return error;

                }
            }
```